# JavaFx Ensemble on Raspberry pi

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi, javafx-8, javafxports

I'm trying to run Esemble8.jar on my new RaspBerry pi. I followed this tutorial: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RaspberryPiFX/raspberryfx.html

I was able to install Java8 but when I try to run the Ensemble8.jar (or any other small JavaFx application) I've this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ensemble.EnsembleApp
```

My PATH is correct; have you some suggestion to fix the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Which JDK8 version are you using?

Comment: root@raspberrypi:~# java -version
java version "1.8.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_33-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.33-b05, mixed mode)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since the 8u33 for ARM version, Oracle has removed JavaFX from the ARM distribution, as it was announced [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk-8u33-arm-relnotes-2406696.html#CACHGFJC).

You can read some statements about this in these forums:

- Raspberry Pi [Forum](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=97367) (now it's offline)
- OpenJFX Mailing [list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2015-January/016570.html)

So you won't be able to run any JavaFX application... unless you downgrade your version to the last JDK8u6 that supported JavaFX, or you provide a valid `jfxrt.jar`.

And you can do it following this [tutorial](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Cross+Building+for+ARM+Hard+Float), cross building OpenJFX for ARM, or just using some already built distribution like this [one](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/arm/downloads) hosted on the JavaFXPorts project.

Once you have downloaded `armv6hf-sdk.zip`, unzip it and you need to add this command line option to attach this external source to the classpath, with the extension mechanism:

```
-Djava.ext.dirs=<path to armv6hf-sdk>/rt/lib/ext
```

For instance, you need this to run one of the JavaFX old samples from its actual path:

```
sudo /opt/jdk1.8.0_33/bin/java -Djava.ext.dirs=<path to armv6hf-sdk>/rt/lib/ext -jar BrickBreaker.jar
```

Comment: You may consider installing (copying or symlinking) the contents of `rt/lib/ext` and `rt/lib/ext` directly into your JVM eg: `/opt/jdk1.8.0_33/jre/lib/ext` and `/opt/jdk1.8.0_33/jre/lib/arm` respectively. This will remove the need to run apps with the `-Djava.ext.dirs=<path to armv6hf-sdk>/rt/lib/ext` directive

Comment: I have tried downloading `armv6hf-sdk.zip` and added it to my project directory. I added 'javafx-mx.jar`, 'jfxrt.jar` and `jfxswt.jar` to my project libraries and in the output directory. However, my pi stil says it can't find the main class.

Comment: @JoëlAbrahams Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40481455/running-javafx-gui-on-the-raspberry-pi/40483500#40483500)

Comment: If anyone has reached here having same error with JavaFX 11/12 + OpenJdk 14, then below command should help: java --module-path "D:\Software\Java\OpenJdk\Windows\11\JavaFX\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics -jar Ensemble8.jar