# JavaFx very slow on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi, java-8, javafxports

I was able to install Java8 + JavaFx on my Raspberry B+ following this tutorial http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RaspberryPiFX/raspberryfx.html and thanks to this suggestion [JavaFx Ensemble on Raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284239/javafx-ensemble-on-raspberry-pi)

I'm able to run Ensemble8 and also a very basic JavaFx test that open a blank stage.
In every case the app is very very very slow. Moving the mouse from one point to another takes several seconds!!!!

Is this performance normal??

Thanks

Comment: are you viewing the screen view remote connection from an other pc or normal HDMI output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dalvik-sdk.zip that was previously available at 
https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/arm/downloads contained experimental code for mobile/embedded. I removed that code, and it works at normal speed again now.

You can download the new sdk at the old location: 
https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/arm/downloads/armv6hf-sdk.zip

Sorry about the confusion, I hope this fixes the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've tested Ensamble8 in both JDK8u33 and JDK8u06, and you are right, now the application goes really slow, while in the previous JDK it went well (considering it's a big application), but without any lag on the mouse.

Maybe it is because `jfxrt.jar` is loaded as external sources, or maybe because there's a huge logging to console while moving the mouse, so I suggest you create an issue on the [repository](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/arm), so they disable the logging in the next build, hoping this will help.