# JavaFX animations running slow on Raspberry Pi

Tags: animation, javafx, raspberry-pi2

I currently have the following problem:

I have created a narrowcasting client for in a shop, which runs on a Raspberry Pi 2B model. Specs: Quad-core 900MHz ARM Cortex A7-processor (BCM2836 chipset), 1024MB RAM LPDDR2 and 16GB MicroSD is of class 10.

I have installed the latest JDK and extended it with the JavaFX packages (as stated in the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372581/cant-find-javafx-in-jdk8-for-arm)). JavaFX is running now, so that should be fine.

However, when I try to run my application, the animations run very slow (see this [video](https://vimeo.com/155941259)). I am using the code below for the animations:

```
public void initImagesTransitions() {

    EventHandler<ActionEvent> fadeIn = event -> {

        TranslateTransition in = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), imageHolder);
        in.setFromY(-(SystemUtils.getScreenHeight()+100));
        in.setToY(-80);
        in.setCycleCount(1);
        in.play();

        imageHolder.setVisible(true);

    };

    EventHandler<ActionEvent> zoomIn = event -> {

        ScaleTransition st = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(5000), imageHolder);
        st.setByX(0.8f);
        st.setByY(0.8f);
        st.setCycleCount(1);
        st.play();

    };

    EventHandler<ActionEvent> fadeOut = event -> {

        TranslateTransition out = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), imageHolder);
        out.setToY(500+SystemUtils.getScreenHeight());
        out.setCycleCount(1);
        out.play();

        out.setOnFinished(e -> imageHolder.setVisible(false));

    };

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, fadeIn),
        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3), zoomIn),
        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(19), fadeOut)
    );

    timeline.playFromStart();

}
```

So nothing special there in my opinion. The Raspberry Pi is only using 30% CPU, so this is also unclear to me. The only other thing running in the background is a like-checker which communicates with my server API every minute.

Anyone any clue on why the animations are slow?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just brainstorming here.

Have you tried toying with -Dprism.order= ... settings?
Like =sw or =j2d?

or increase vram on your PI?

(also this does seem relevant: 
[javafx-very-slow-on-raspberry-pi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295712/javafx-very-slow-on-raspberry-pi?rq=1)
)

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I will try these suggestions. The link doesnt seem to be relevant, because I use the correct JavaFX package.

Comment: Using j2d the animations are much smoother, thank you for that! However, are the more settings for -Dprism.order and where to find them?

Comment: Also increased the VRAM in config, 128MB is much better and still enough processing capabilities! Thanks for this answer once again!