# How to run javafx on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi, java-8, raspbian

I have an app which uses some simple JavaFX classes.  I'm under the impression that java 8 is supposed to include these classes by default.  However when I run a very simple test on my Raspberry Pi running `oracle-java8-jdk` (just try to create a [Media](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) object) I get an error showing the class isn't found.  I don't get this error on my PC when attempting to run the same test with the same jar file:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/media/Media
        at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.media.Media
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

If I check the java version I have in stalled I shows:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

Have I missed something obveous here?  Do I need to do something special to enable these JavaFX classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, according to [OpenJFX](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/OpenJFX+on+the+Raspberry+Pi):

> JDK 8 EA builds for the Raspberry Pi include full support for hardware accelerated graphics, with everything from the base, graphics, controls and FXML modules. Media and Web modules are not included.

So early access builds, like yours, never included access to media. And it wasn't included in the final release for ARM 1.8.0_06 (8u6).

What's more, in the new release 1.8.0_33, JavaFX is no longer supported and it was removed from the ARM bundled.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284239/javafx-ensemble-on-raspberry-pi/28284736#28284736) for more details on this. You still will be able to use JavaFX on your Raspberry Pi, but Media is not an option.

Comment: Thanks.  Completely stunned that Oracle broke RORA on this.  As the question you linked points out I'll get a hold of a third party library for it.