# JavaFX8 build to run Web module on Raspberry Pi

Tags: javafx, raspberry-pi, gluon, azul-zulu

Can someone recommend known to work non-Oracle based setup (JVM+JavaFX) to run JavaFX app with Web module support on Raspberry Pi/Raspbian 8 (jessie)?

The only JavaFX builds for armv6hf/Pi I could find were Gluon, Bellsoft and Chris Newland's.
Out of these three only Gluon and Chris's had Web support, v8 only. And both failed to run
on Azul's zulu8 jdk, different issues. Thanks.

Comment: Gluon's JDK for [embedded on JDK 1.8](https://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/javafxports/get/) should work fine with any recent Java 1.8 (Oracle's or OpenJDK). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40481455/running-javafx-gui-on-the-raspberry-pi/40483500#40483500).

Comment: @JoséPereda, thank you. You are correct that Gluon's JavaFX v8 (I tested armv6hf-sdk-8.60.9.zip) works with older Oracle JDK v8 (tested jdk-8u192-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz), however we can't use their recent releases since they changed license on April 16, 2019. The same Gluon armv6hf-sdk-8.60.9.zip doesn't work with Azul's JDK v8, that's why I wondered if someone has working non-Oracle JDK + JavaFX/Web setup to share install details.

Comment: Tested https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u232-b09/OpenJDK8U-jdk_arm_linux_hotspot_8u232b09.tar.gz and it also doesn't work with Gluon armv6hf-sdk-8.60.9.zip, crashing with error message: "A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: Internal Error (os_linux_zero.cpp:254) fatal error: caught unhandled signal 11"